# Visual Studio Code: How to Include another language in a user defined language?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, tmlanguage

I have downloaded a plugin for Language A. It is at `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions\langA\syntaxes`. There is a file `langA.tmLanguage`. It is XML.

I am creating Language B. I have a JSON `.tmLanguage` file. I have already added some custom coloring and folding rules. I would like to inherit Language A's syntax when it is embedded in Language B between `START_MARKER` and `END_MARKER`. Is this possible? Can someone help with the JSON syntax to accomplish this?

Bonus Question: Can anyone point me to a real simple hover example not using a language server? I would like to create a hover that takes the word with the cursor and searches the document for `DEF_MARKER word` to display in the hover. I am struggling with the real language examples due to my lack of experience in these languages and the complexity involved in, say, the Go example or other plugins I have downloaded.

Comment: You can find some examples by searching in github

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it.

```
{
    "name": "entity.name.tag",
    "begin": "^START_MARKER",
    "end": "^END_MARKER",
    "patterns": [
        {
            "include": "source.LangA"
        }
    ]           
}
```

Comment: For future people finding this: Most languages are "source.lang" eg "source.php", except for HTML (and maybe others?) which for some reason is "text.html.basic". It tripped me up at first.